# Return array a if given number is in it, return array a and the given number if it is not

Tags: ruby, arrays

Here's what I thought:

```
def appendUnique(a,x)
    for i in 0 .. a.size-1 do
        if a[i]=x then
            a==a
        else
            a=a+x
        end

        p(a)
    end
end

appendUnique([-1,5,3],4)
```

Compare each member of a with x, if a equals x, return a, else return a+x. Why doesn't this work? It just replaces all array members with 4s...
I want this: result [-1, 5, 3, 4] from the above since 4 isn't in the array and [-1, 5, 3] from appendUnique([-1,5,3],5).

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues with your code:

- in Ruby we usually use `each` instead of `for` to iterate collections
- `a[i] = x` is an *assignment*, you want `a[i] == x`
- `a == a` just returns `true`
- `a + x` concatenates two *arrays*, but `x` is not an array

I would simply use [`Array#include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) to check if the item is present:

```
def appendUnique(array, item)
  if array.include? item
    array
  else
    array + [item]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array with unique elements you can use [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) class

Answer (score 0):

> It just replaces all array members with 4s...

`a[i]=x` is an assignment rather than comparison. Running this in a loop, as you do, would set every element of `a` to `x` (which is 4).

The rest of the code needs quite a lot of work too. For example: you should only be appending to `a` *after* you've run the loop and have established that `x` isn't in the array.

Comment: it's ruby, forgot to mention that.

Comment: When I write loops, I try to get the results of each run first - helps me spot errors. So this is why I'm appending to a within the loop.